# Filling a dictionary of lists with class instances

Tags: python, list, class, dictionary

I want to fill a dictionary with lists. The lists should contain instances of a class.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, start, stop):
        self.start = start
        self.stop = stop
```

Here's what I tried so far:

```
dict = {}  # create empty dictionary
for i in range(5):  # 5 keys in the dictionary
    for j,k in zip(range(3),[1,10,100]):  # list for each key: 1,10,100
        dict[i][j] = MyClass(0,k)
```

My desired output is:

```
print(dict[0][0].stop)
   1

print(dict[0][1].stop)
   10

print(dict[0][2].stop)
   100
```

So that in the first square bracket I can specify the key and in the second square bracket the index of the list entry.

Comment: What do you want the final dict to look like, in this case? The example is small enough that you should be able to type it out in full, and it will be a lot easier to understand your intent.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the concept of a dictionary. You do not want to access a dictionary with an index. You want to access it with a key.

Comment: Oops I phrased that badly. In the first square bracket I want to specify the key and in the second the index of the list

Comment: Still, why are you using a dictionary? Use a list of lists instead, if you're just accessing it with an index. You name it key, but you just misuse it as an index.

Comment: Oh right, that might be what I need. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

A very important note first: **Never** use `dict` as variable name as it is a reserved keyword for dictionaries!

Why not simply assign the list to the respective key? Like so:

```
d = {}
for i in range(5):
    d[i] = [1, 10, 100]
```

A much easier and readable approach is, when you use a `dictionary comprehension` instead:

```
d = {k : [1, 10, 100] for k in range(5)}
```

---

**EDIT:**

From what I understand from your comments, it seems like you are misusing a dictionary. If you want to simply access something by index you should consider using a `tuple` or `list`. My suggestion for your use case:

```
classes = [[MyClass(0,k) for k in [1,10,100]] for _ in range(5)]

print(classes[0][0].stop) # 1
print(classes[0][1].stop) # 10
print(classes[0][2].stop) # 100
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I just realised that I simplified my question too much. I actually want to have a dictionary of lists where the lists contain Class instances. The first class instance should have 1 as an attribute, the second 10 and the third instance 100 as an attribute.

Comment: Can you please add the desired output to your question, so everybody knows what you want to achieve.

Comment: I updated the question. Can you understand what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Actually i do not. Can you please justify, why you are using a dictionary, when you are accessing it by some index.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you aren't adding any lists to your dictionary here. If you want to use this approach, add a list on each iteration:

```
for i in range(5):  # 5 keys in the dictionary
    dict[i] = [] # add a list
    for j,k in zip(range(3),[1,10,100]):  # list for each key: 1,10,100
        dict[i].append(k)
```

You can also do it in one line with a dictionary comprehension:

```
the_dict = {i: [1,10,100] for i in range(5)}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
dict = {}  # create empty dictionary
for i in range(5):  # 5 keys in the dictionary
    dict[i] = []
    for k in [1,10,100]:  # list for each key: 1,10,100
        dict[i].append(k)
```